# How to insert data into corda?

Tags: corda

I have medical data.

I want to prepare a case study and insert these medical data into corda platform.

How can I insert data into corda software?

I installed Corda Demo Bench software but it does not have such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Corda is not a software that you can just "insert" data and use. Corda is a platform that has applications sit on top of it. That is, you need to build your own Corda application to suit your business uses.

And the data part that you are mentioning will be the `State` in your Cordapp. More information can be found at https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-states.html

If you are looking for a ready-to-use solution, R3 has a Corda solution marketplace @https://marketplace.r3.com/dashboard